# defining routes with parameters in laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

in Laravel i want to do a page with a search box and a form (the route could be /products)
I want to retrieve information using search box typing id  from a db and populate the form.
I request datas with the route for example /products/{id}

But in the controller i use the same function products($Request request) with if the id exists do something if no do other things, or there are two different functions?
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go through the [Laravel Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers).

To show list of products i.e. `/products`, create a **index()** method. To show a specific product i.e. `/product/{id}`, create **show()** method.

[image]

Comment: but if my index is already ocupied by another page index? Can call with another name? Or i need a new controller? :S

Comment: You are free to use another name. No need to create a new controller. The above image is a standard way of doing it. You can say `listProducts()`

Comment: A problem i defined so 2 routes Route::get('/gestisci', 'RefundsController@indexRefunds');
Route::get('/gestisci/{polizza}', 'RefundsController@showRefunds'); why if i call http://......./rimborsi/gestisci?findPolizza=123123 it calls also indexRefunds method???? THxs a lot!!

Comment: Try this `.../gestisci/123123`

Answer (score 0):

Probably is better use the same function, if id exist, return the page with the values filling the form, if not returns the same page but with a message showing that product doesn't exist